# Bind Kendo UI treeview to Json data returned by ASP.Net .ashx handler

Tags: asp.net, json, kendo-ui

I want to create a simply treeview with the Kendo UI treeview widjet.

I read the documentation, but I can't go further the first step: Bind a simple, simple non-nested json value:

In my head section i put:

```
 <script>

       $(document).ready(function () {

         var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({

               transport: {
                   read: {
                       url: "kendoTWData.ashx",   
                       dataType: "json" 

                   }
               },
               schema: {
                   model: {
                       id: "EmployeeId",
                       FullName: "FullName"
                   }
               }


           });

           $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
               dataSource: homogeneous,
               dataTextField: "FullName",
               dataValueField: "id"
           });
           });


        </script>
```

The handler "kendoTWData.ashx" correctly return: {"EmployeeId":1,"FullName":"AName"}
But nothing appears.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should return an `array` and not an `object`. It should be:

```
[{"EmployeeId":1,"FullName":"AName"}]
```

This is because the `tree` might have multiple `nodes` at `root` level.

Comment: Fixed... :)
Thank-you OnaBai!!